# update one column in two tables

Tags: sql

I need to turn the following statement into an update statement where I'm updating the Update column shared between 2 tables on 1 record:

```
select n.updated 
from note n, opportunity_note oo 
where n.NOTE_ID = oo.note_id 
  and oo.opportunity_id = 3525634
```

I'm having to update both tables separately right now and would like to be able to do it only 1 time.

Comment: You **cannot** update two tables at once in SQL - you need to do this in two steps, one table at a time

Comment: A query such as `UPDATE ta JOIN tb ON ta.id = tb.id SET ta.value = "Foo", tb.value = "Bar" WHERE ta.id = 1;` updates two tables at once. (Tested on MySQL 5.6.17) Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JYelton That query would only update ta. It would first do the join and check for the values, but it still updates only one table.

Comment: @Jenn I tested and verified that it updated both `ta` and `tb` - so I am questioning that you can only update one table at a time. Maybe that applies to Microsoft SQL Server instead of MySQL?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Your question doesn't indicate any `column shared between 2 tables` that needs to be updated. What column(s) do you want to update? The column would seem to be `NOTE_ID`, but that would normally be an identifier and probably shouldn't be "updated".

Answer (score 0):

An update statement will update only one table at a time, it cannot update two or more at once.

Comment: This depends on the DBMS being used. Quote from the [MySQL manual]("*https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html): "*For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in **each** table*". In Postgres one could use a data-modifying CTE to update more than one table in single statement (which would contain more than one `UPDATE` statement though)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you just want this (MySQL syntax):

```
update n
    from note n join
         opportunity_note oo 
         on n.NOTE_ID = oo.note_id 
    set n.updated = NEWVALUE
    where oo.opportunity_id = 3525634;
```

The generic SQL for this is:

```
update note 
   set n.updated = NEWVALUE
   where exists (select 1
                 from opportunity_note oo
                 where note.NOTE_ID = oo.note_id and oo.opportunity_id = 3525634
                );
```

This should work in any SQL database.

If you have two columns in two tables that you want to update, you can do this in MySQL, but not in most other databases.  The syntax is simply:

```
update n
    from note n join
         opportunity_note oo 
         on n.NOTE_ID = oo.note_id 
    set n.updated = NEWVALUE,
        oo.updated = NEWVALUE
    where oo.opportunity_id = 3525634;
```

select n.updated 
from note n, opportunity_note oo 
where n.NOTE_ID = oo.note_id 
  and oo.opportunity_id = 3525634